# Sum of 3 numbers in AP is 21 and their product is 231. Find the numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This problem is to be solved by using high school math only. The answer is that numbers are 3,7,11. The solution includes assuming that the required numbers be `a`, `a-d`, `a+d` . But i am not able to understand why we are assuming these , since its not given that the numbers is consecutive in the AP, so all we know that they can be of form `a`, `a+nd`, `a+md` . A similar question which says that numbers are consecutive in the given AP has a similar assumption that numbers are `a`, `a-d`, `a+d`. but why can't the numbers be `a` , `a+d` , or `a+2d`?

Comment: I think this is a semantic issue.  Saying $3$ numbers are in arithmetic progression means that they are of the form you describe, $a-d, a, a+d$.  This is the same as letting them be $a, a + d, a + 2d$ by the way since the common difference is still $d$.

Comment: In think "in arithmetic progression" always means "consecutive" implicitly, or all integers are in "in arithmetic progression." If they really wanted you to allow $a,a+md,a+nd$, they'd say, that the three numbers are members of the same arithmetic progression, not "in arithmetic progression."

Comment: (Repost because of bad writing.) By the way, you never mention anything about arithmetic progression in the original problem until you get to your comments. Please state the full problem in the body of your message, so we can see the whole problem up front (which is currently missing - we have to infer the arithmetic progression part of the problem from later comments.)

Comment: muzzlator is right. *Numbers in AP* is different from *terms of an AP* and is similar to *consecutive terms of an AP* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the numbers be $a-d,a$ and $a+d$, clearly $d$ is the common difference.

So, $a-d+a+a+d=21\implies 3a=21\implies a=7$

and $a(a-d)(a+d)=231\implies 7(7^2-d^2)=231$
$\implies 7^2-d^2=33\implies d^2=16\implies d=\pm4$

So, the numbers are $7,7\pm4$ i.e, $3,7,11$

---

If we take the numbers to be $a,a+d,a+2d$ where $d$ is the common difference,

$a+a+d+a+2d=21\implies a+d=7,a=7-d$

Now, $a(a+d)(a+2d)=231\implies (7-d)7(7+d)=231\implies 7^2-d^2=33\implies d=\pm4$

Comment: Of course, if you take $a,a+d,a+2d$, then you let $a'=a+d$ and you've again got $a'-d,a',a'+d$...

Answer (score 0):

The numbers can be $a, a+d, a+2d$.  Instead, they chose to start counting at term $-1$ instead of $0$.  This made it easier to solve the simultaneous equations because the sum becomes $a-d+a+a+d=3a$ and you get $a=7$ immediately.

If we want to use $a,a+d,a+2d$ we get $3a+3d=21$ or $a+d=7$  Then from the product we have $a(a+d)(a+2d)=7a(7+d)=231,\ \  a(7+d)=33,\ \ (7-d)(7+d)=33=49-d^2$ which you can solve  to get $d=4, a=3$ or $d=-4,a=11$

Comment: You don't need to solve by inspection since $(7-d)(7+d)=49-d^2$ so you can solve directly. Inspection works here, but perhaps not as edifying as a solution that would work if $33$ were some other number.

Answer (score 0):

We are assuming (a-d), a , (a+d) to simple our problem. Since we know that those numbers which are consecutive are in A.P. so we choose it that way. We can choose a,a+d, a+2d, but that will just lead us to a big calculation. We can solve it like this

Let numbers be a,a+d, a+2d
now, a+(a+d)+(a+2d)= 21
     3a+3d=21
     a+d=7

Again. a.(a+d).(a+2d)= 231
       a.7.(7+d)=231
       (7-d).(7+d)=33
        49-d^2=33
        d=4 or -4

and we get a= 3 or 11

and thus we get the numbers as 3,7,11.