# Representing Arithmetic Progression with different variables for given number of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

The sum of four consecutive terms which are in an arithmetic progression is $32$ and the ratio of the products of the first and last terms to the product of the middle terms is $7:15$. Find the AP.

I know it's possible to solve this by taking the terms as

$$a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d$$

And even found an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315994/sum-of-3-numbers-in-ap-is-21-and-their-product-is-231-find-the-numbers) which explained that the way you represent terms doesn't matter but I am still not able to solve this question with terms as other variables such as

$1)$ $a-2d,a-d,a+d,a+2d$

$2)$ $a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d$

Can anyone solve this with the terms in $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

The AP is 2,6,10,14 but how will you find it with (1) or (2)?

Comment: How'd you get
$$
a- 3d, \quad a-d, \quad a+d, \quad a+3d
$$
? Here, the difference between successive terms is $2d$ ?!

Comment: Can you solve the problem in any of these forms?

Comment: You will struggle with $1)$ because you missed $\color{red}{a}$ term out
\begin{eqnarray*}
a-2d,a-d,\color{red}{a},a+d,a+2d.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @MattiP. I searched the question on Google first before asking here and the answers took the AP as a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d.

Comment: I agree Matti, whether the answer to the linked question is accepted or not, if we use this approach, then clearly, $d$ has another meaning. Whether it makes the answer easier or not, the usual approach with $\ a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d\ $ should be easy enough and directly solves the given problem.

Comment: If we take the AP as a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d. With this we can get a=8 on addition of the terms. Putting the value of a in the eq. (a+3d)(a-3d)/(a+d)(a-d) and solving further I ended up the a²=16d². Putting the value of a, we get d as ±4

Comment: So if a is 8 and d is ±2 then AP should be 2,6,10,14 or its reverse.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the second case,

the sum will be

$$4a+6d=32$$
or
$$3d+2a=16$$

But 
$$3\times 16  - 2\times 16=16$$

thus
$$3(16-d) = 2(a+16)$$
and since $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime,

$$d =16 - 2k \text{ and } a= 3k-16$$

the second equation is

$$\frac{a(a+3d)}{(a+d)(a+2d)}=\frac{7}{15}$$

gives 
$$\frac{(3k-16)(32-3k)}{k(16-k)}=\frac{7}{15}$$

and $k=6$, $a=2$ , $d=4$.
The four terms are
$$\boxed{2, 6, 10, 14}$$

Comment: If you put 16 in the eq. 2a+3d=16 then are you **assuming** a=d?

Comment: @Draphic No, i just divided by $2$ the first equation which gives the sum $32$.

Comment: No I meant that you had put 16 in eq. 3a+2a but why? So the AP can be written as k-d,k,k+d,k+2d where k-d is a? Sorry but I couldn't understand after 3d+2a=16, can you cite some examples (of that putting of 16 and relatively prime) or please elaborate.